# How to solve a system of quadratic equations with multiple unknowns?

Tags: algebraic-equations

While solving a problem i have ended up with these 4 equations:

a^2+b^2= p;

(c-q)^2+d^2=r;

(d-b)/(c-a)=s;

(c-a)^2-(d-b)^2=t

Here a,b,c,d are unknowns . The rest (p,q,r,s,t) are known values. I am looking only for the real solutions.

How can i solve the system?